# Register context with parameter (service) in .net core using autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

This is constructor of my context:

```
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options, ICurrentUserService currentUserService) : base(options)
{
    _currentUserService = currentUserService;
}
```

as you can see there is also service injected as parameter.

I registered service:

```
builder.RegisterType<CurrentUserService>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

And my context:

```
private void RegisterContext(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
    options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);

    builder.Register(container => new MyContext(options.Options, ???WHAT_SHOULD_BE_HERE???)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

But I'm not sure how should I register this context with that service.

Comment: what is the expected parameter type ? could you share the constructor of `MyContext` ?

Comment: Is already there, at the beginning of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could resolve the desired service

```
builder.Register(container => 
    new MyContext(options.Options, container.Resolve<ICurrentUserService>())
)
.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Or just register all the necessary types

```
private void RegisterContext(ContainerBuilder builder) {
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
    options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    builder.RegisterInstance(options.Options).As<DbContextOption<MyContext>>();

    builder.RegisterType<CurrentUserService>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```